IO Of Socket IO not importing in node
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const userRouter = require('./appRouter');

app.use(cors());

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3002",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("A user connected");

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('User disconnected');
    });
});

// Route handler for /api
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    // Emit a message to all connected clients when /api is accessed
    io.emit('message', 'Message from /api route');
    return res.send({
        message: "OK"
    });
});

app.use('/users', userRouter);


server.listen(4001, () => {
    console.log("Server running fine on 4001");
});


exports.getInfo = () => {
    return io
}


const express = require("express");
const  {getInfo}  = require("./app");
const userRouter = express.Router();

const fun = (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log("TYPE", typeof getInfo)
        const io = getInfo();
        io.emit("message", "OK")
        res.send({
            message: "OK"
        })
    } catch (error) {
        return res.send({
            message: error.message
        })
    }

}
userRouter.get("/add", fun);

module.exports = userRouter;


here my two files when i directly export the io from app.js. It says io.emit is not a function but when i use this approach it says getIo is not a function stuck from last 2 days any better approach to export io.
